# What is the best way to map sql JOIN results to objects?

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

I need to map SQL `Join` results to objects. For example, there are two tables `Categories` and `Products` with one-to-many relationship. I need to map them to class which looks like:

```
public class CategoryInfo
{
   public Category Category {get;set;}
   public List<Product> Products {get;set}
}
```

The problem is that I have to use `SqlDataReader` and map it's rows to `CategoryInfo` objects. This is the requirement. I am not allowed to make joins in-memory.
And this is the simplest case, multiple joins (more than two tables) and many-to-many relationships also happen. Do you have any suggestions how to do this in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some ORM libraries like Entity Framework or NHibernate

Comment: I am not allowed to do this, as I have noticed in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your VO class also should look like so:

```
 public class Category
 {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    .....
    public List<Product> Products {get;set}
 }
```

so you can fill each category with its products, once you pull all the categories  you pull the products to each category

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are not allowed to use an ORM, you could use a generic method to pull your data into objects from a **DataTable** as follows:

```
    public static List<T> DataTableToEntities<T>(DataTable dt)
    {
        string propName = string.Empty;
        List<T> entityList = new List<T>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {                
            T entity = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in  entityProperties)
            {
                propName = item.Name;

                if (dt.Columns.Contains(propName))
                {                  
                    item.SetValue
                    (
                        entity,
                        dr[propName].GetType().Name.Equals(typeof(DBNull).Name)? null : dr[propName],
                        null
                    );
                }
            }
            entityList.Add(entity);
        }
        return entityList;
    }
```

The above method **matches your DataTable columns to class properties.** Your DataTable column just needs have the same name as your class property for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into simillar problem. So after the query execution you have the whole table in your data reader. The table rows consist of Category info and associated product. There are also more rows for one category - its one to many relationship. So the thing i have done was to sort the table by Category id. After that i iterate throught the table rows and compare the actual row with the last processed. If the ID's are the same, i know i am still on the same Category and i can map new product to it `(sth like Categories.Last().Add(new Product{...}))` otherwise i create new Category and add it to Categories list. At the end of only one iteration through the table i have list of Categories with all the products linked to the correct category.